# How to map all properties of one object to another bigger object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to map one array of object to another array of object like the following code, but compiler is asking me to fill the remaining properties of `Original` object.

```
export interface Original {
    a: string,
    b: string,
    c: string,
    d: string,
    e: string    
}

export interface Review {
    a_1: string,
    b_1: string          
}

export class NewClass{
    originals!:Original[];
    reviews!:Review[];

    constructor() {        
        this.originals = this.reviews.map(review => ({
            a:review.a_1,
            b:review.b_1,
            c:"", //I don't want to do this
        }))
    }
}
```

**Question** - How to avoid filling all the remaining properties of object `Original`?

**Error** - [image: compiler Error]

**Note** - making properties `c`, `d` and `e` optional mitigates the compiler error but I am not allowed modify the models.

Comment: Please make your code a [mre] that demonstrates your issue if I paste it into my own IDE.  Right now this is either pseudocode or excerpted code; regardless, I see a lot of IDE errors that presumably have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to "avoid" filling the remaining properties? What, specifically, do you want the elements of the `originals` array to be?  I mean, either you fill them or they will be `undefined`. Which one of those is acceptable?

Comment: @jcalz I am perfectly all right with them being undefined or null or empty as that is what I am forced to do just to please the compiler.

Comment: If you are okay with them being `undefined` then either you have to make the compiler okay with that, at which point you're using `Pick<Original, "a" | "b">` instead of `Original`, or you're *lying* to the compiler about it by asserting that it is actually `Original` when it's not.  Both options are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpj5zw).  Do either of those meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want optional properties:

```js
type Original = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
    c?: string,
    d?: string,
    e?: string        
}

type Review = {
    a_1: string,
    b_1: string      
}
```

`c`, `d`, and `e` now have type `string | undefined`.

---

Since this is impossible in your situation, you can make a function to initialize missing properties to a default value. You'll still have to write them all out once, but it's good if you'll be doing this multiple times.

```js
function initOriginal(props: Partial<Original>): Original {
  return {
    a: props.a || '',
    b: props.b || '',
    c: props.c || '',
    d: props.d || '',
    e: props.e || '',
  };
}

export class NewClass {
  originals!: Original[];
  reviews!: Review[];

  constructor() {
    this.originals = this.reviews.map((review) =>
      initOriginal({
        a: review.a_1,
        b: review.b_1,
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The function takes a `Partial<T>` type, which sets all properties of `T` to optional. It then returns the original type, with any `undefined` properties set to an empty string.

---

It may also suit your use case to just type your property as a `Partial<Original>` instead. Depends if you need the non-partial type for something else like a function call.

```js
export class NewClass {
  originals!: Partial<Original>[];
  reviews!: Review[];

  constructor() {
    this.originals = this.reviews.map((review) => ({
      a: review.a_1,
      b: review.b_1,
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: The objects are defined for me, i.e. I don’t have the liberty to modify the models.

Comment: The original object has like 34 properties in it :(

Comment: @VivekShukla you could make a class constructor or a function that initializes an `Original`, where properties are initialized to an empty string if not provided. That way you'd only need to write it out once.

Comment: could you show me how, an example would be great.

Comment: @VivekShukla I added an example

Comment: Just curious, how the implementation is different than what I had originally, i.e.
 `this.originals = this.reviews.map(review => ({ a:review.a_1,  b:review.b_1,  c:"", d: "", e: "" }))`

Comment: @VivekShukla it's reusable if you'll be doing the same thing again.